# Failed to register a ServiceWorker (404 error) using WebEssentials.AspNetCore.PWA

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, service-worker, razor-pages

I've been adding WebEssentials.AspNetCore.PWA to several of my sites recently and it's all gone very easily, (to be fair it's very easy to install).

But one site is giving me a real headache and is always reporting the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://dawson-floridavilla.co.uk/') with script ('https://dawson-floridavilla.co.uk/serviceworker'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

I also receive a 404 error for manifest.webmanifest.

If I try to navigate to https://dawson-floridavilla.co.uk/serviceworker I receive a 404 error where the other sites all show the ServiceWorker JavaScript code.

The site isn't very complicated so I'm not sure what to strip back to test for any incompatibilities, all four sites I've attempted/implemented are ASP.NET Core 3.1 running on a Windows 10 VS Studio Dev Server or a Debian 10 Production Server.

Has anybody else had similar issues? I think the package is attempting to run as it adds the lines for the serviceworker script and the webmanifest but both return 404 errors as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After submitting my issue on Github I realised that this site is purely Razor Pages whereas my other sites are a mix of MVC (for API routes) and Razor Pages.

This means that the other sites have controllers added and mapped in ConfigureServices and EndPoint Routing but not in this project which is something the package needs to map the additional code.

I've posted this on StackOverflow and Github for the community interest mainly because Microsoft is promoting Razor Pages as the way forward over MVC and other folks may fall over the same issue in the future.